# springboard.icons["appName"] does not recognize the installed app in XCUITest

Tags: ios, ui-automation, xcuitest

I am referring to the below github code to delete the app after running every XCUItest. 
https://gist.github.com/KoCMoHaBTa/5d2cecfc17db5f3944bc98bcd6fcde55

But the code snippet let icon = springboard.icons["myAppName"] does not recognize my app. I have replaced myAppName with my app name and the if condition that checks if icon.exists always returns false.  The springboard class looks as below. Am I missing anything here.

```
class Springboard {

    static let shared = Springboard()

    let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.company.me")

    func deleteApp(withName name: String) {

        XCUIApplication().terminate()

        let springboard = self.springboard
        //springboard.resolve()
        springboard.activate()
        let icon = springboard.icons[name]
        sleep(5)
        //let icon = springboard.icons.matching(identifier: "ONE").firstMatch
        //let icon = springboard.otherElements["Home screen icons"].scrollViews.otherElements.icons["ONE"]
        if icon.exists {

            let iconFrame = icon.frame
            let springboardFrame = springboard.frame

            //Tap & Hold the app icon in order to go to edit mode
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
            icon.press(forDuration: 1.3)

            //Tap the little "X" button at approximately where it is. The X is not exposed directly
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
            springboard.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: (iconFrame.minX + 5) / springboardFrame.maxX, dy: (iconFrame.minY + 5) / springboardFrame.maxY)).tap()

            //tap the delete alert button
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
            springboard.alerts.buttons["Delete"].tap()
        }

        //Press home once make the icons stop wiggling
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
        XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
    }
}
```

Comment: When executing this piece of code, is the app icon visible on the Springboard page ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. Are you saying if app icon is visible on the simulator when the above piece of code is being executed? If yes, then yes, it is visible. Otherwise I do not understand what you mean by springboard page.

Answer (score 0):

You shall probably change `bundleIdentifier`

`let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")`

---

Also, you can delete your app using the `simctl` tool

`xcrun simctl uninstall --help`